# Replace delimiter in file without changing field content

Tags: bash, awk

I have to bulk load into an Oracle database a file with spaces as delimiter. The problem is that any of the fields contain spaces as well, like this

```
os linux good 1
os mac good 1
os windows bad 3
os unknown not clear 0
```

I have tried this Awk command but it also replaces the spaces in the fields themselves

```
cslamdi0416:~ user1$ awk '$1=$1' FS=" " OFS="|" myfile
os|linux|good|1
os|mac|good|1
os|windows|bad|3
os|unknown|not|clear|0
```

I don't want that. Is there a way to produce this output

```
os linux|good|1
os mac|good|1
os windows|bad|3
os unknown|not clear|0
```

?? I believe I need to use the NF variable to specify the number of fields but I am not clear how to do that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you know when a space is inside a field vs between fields? Is it always the first space that's inside? Always the 3rd from the end? Something else? Is there always only one space inside a field or can there be many? Edit your question to clarify and provide better coverage with your sample if necessary.

Comment: Corrected verbiage and modified example.

Comment: If we named the 4 columns `type`, `name`, `condition` and `grade`, can there be any assumptions such as only column `grade` can have extra spaces? Or at least that column `type` and column `grade` do not?
If both this: `os unknown not clear 0` and this: `os windows 10 good 0` or  `os windows 10 not clear 0` are possible then there is non automatic way.

Comment: Yes, the only hope is to put some kind of formal structure on the input. If we only know that "any field can have spaces" it's hard to proceed. Is column1 always "os" followed by one word? Is column 2 always one of "good", "bad", or "not clear"?  Is column three always a single integer? That kind of thing.

Comment: Furthermore could provide a dictionary for any of the columns? An example would be for the column `condition`, could the values be only `['good','bad','not clear']`?

Comment: You have GOT to put some effort into telling us how to identify spaces within vs between columns. Right now we have no clue.

Comment: The (real) file in question has over 30 million records.  A dictionary of value is not realistic as the real data is a dump of a transaction table from a search engine. The columns causing the problems are character based columns. I noticed the "errand" spaces while attempting to bulk load the data. A cursory review of the file (eyeballed it) shows that it is absolutely random. I am sorry if that's not good enough.

Comment: It's not just "not good enough", it's completely impossible to do anything with. Given random non-field-separator spaces can occur in a file there is just no way to programmatically find them and handle them differently from the other field-separator spaces in the file since `a b c` could mean `a;b c` or `a b;c` or `a;b;c` or `a b c` (using `;` to highlight field separation).

Comment: Can you as a human being look at any of the 30 million records and know where to put the "|" delimiters? If so, how do you know?  If not, neither can awk.  Meanwhile, depending on your ultimate goal, there are things you can do, but you probably want to add some tags to bring some other people into the mix. People who are used to dealing with large amounts of unstructured data and pulling out some useful info.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v OFS="|" ' NF==4 {print $1" " $2, $3, $4} NF!=4 {print "Error in fmt:" $0}' file
```

should meet your stated needs.

**output**

```
os linux|good|1
os mac|good|1
os windows|bad|3
```

The 2nd block highlights any records that do not contain 4 fields. If you don't want an error message, then replace with

```
NF!=4 {print}
```

IHTH

Comment: Actually my example is misleading (my bad). There can be spaces in any field. Not just the first one.

Answer (score 0):

`awk '{print $1" "$2"|"$3"|"$4}' FS=" " myfile`

Output:

```
os linux|good|1
os mac|good|1
os windows|bad|3
```

Another approach to sepearate only the first with `space` and the rest with `|` is this:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if(i==1) {printf "%s ", $i} else if(i==NF) {printf "%s\n", $i} else {printf "%s|", $i}}' myfile
```

Comment: you are right. http://superuser.com/questions/323060/what-is-the-general-consensus-on-useless-use-of-cat